# DMQ usage in Payara

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, payara

How to use dead message queue (DMQ) in Payara Application Server?

While creating new JMS Destination Resource with destination name mq.sys.dmq, it says:

```
Unable to create admin object. Reason: Destination Resource jms/mq.sys.dmq has an invalid destination name mq.sys.dmq
```

In glassfish there wasn't any error with this name

Comment: Is there any more detail in the error? Was this the physical name or JNDI name? IIRC, a `/` character is OK in a JNDI name, but not physical name

Comment: @Mike Log file prints just this  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'https://localhost:11048/management/domain/resources/create-jms-resource'; attrs = '{resType=javax.jms.Queue, name=jms/mq.sys.dmq, property=Name=mq.sys.dmq, description=null, force=false, enabled=true}', but in admin gui it says Unable to create admin object. Reason: Destination Resource jms/mq.sys.dmq has an invalid destination name mq.sys.dmq. I have problem with destination name not jndi.

Comment: Odd. This message comes from only 1 place in the code and that has existed for >5 years (older than GF 4.0) ([CreateJMSResource.java](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blame/d9a48c4be979ca3087285d7a23549e93cc413425/appserver/jms/admin/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jms/admin/cli/CreateJMSResource.java#L468-L474)) so you should see the same behaviour in GlassFish as Payara Server......

Comment: ......When you look further down at the [`isSyntaxValid()` method in that class](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blame/d9a48c4be979ca3087285d7a23549e93cc413425/appserver/jms/admin/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jms/admin/cli/CreateJMSResource.java#L501-L525), it specifically prevents the creation of queues starting with `mq.`

Comment: ah, ok, I found it. This is actually incorrect behaviour in GlassFish which was fixed in Payara Server with [PAYARA-734](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/847/files). Creating a JMS destination resource via the admin console did not call `create-jms-resource` under the covers, so that an invalid (and unusable) destination would be created, as described in [GLASSFISH-16039](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16039)

Comment: @Mike, as I understand you, my problem is using "mq." prefix for destination name, because of [method in that class](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blame/d9a48c4be979ca3087285d7a23549e93cc413425/appserver/jms/admin/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jms/admin/cli/CreateJMSResource.java#L468-L474) But, how to use then destination mq.sys.dmq of glassfish(or payara)?

Comment: AFAIK, the dmq is a system queue, so shouldn't need to be created - it's already there. See the bottom of section **7-10** on page 90 of the [OpenMQ Admin Guide \[pdf\]](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/mq-admin-guide.pdf) "***The broker automatically creates a dead message queue when it starts.***"

Comment: @Mike, thanx for your help. Link you sent is broken. But, I could create resource for DMQ by console create-jms-resource. Cannot undersand, why there is validation for mq prefix in admin ui while it can be easily bypass thru console. Now, I am using this created dmq resource to get messages from dmq.

Comment: java.net has gone dark since I posted that, the new location for the docs is here:
https://javaee.github.io/openmq/Documentation.html